# How to load data in second component of UIPickerView from first component selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, uipickerview

I have tried to find a solution for my problem for over a week now but no success with other similar questions on this website.

I have multiple NSMutableArrays for my pickerView and I'm trying to set the second component's data based on first component's selection. My main problem is that the second component's data is empty when I select anything other than the first choice in the first component. When the first choice in the first component is selected, I have all my arrays together one after the other in my second component but I want only 1 array per component data.

This is my code in the ViewController.h:

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

{
    NSMutableArray *maListeTrier;
    NSMutableArray *maListeTypes;
    NSMutableArray *maListeSousTypes;
    NSMutableArray *maListeSousTypes2;
    NSMutableArray *maListeSousTypes3;
    NSMutableArray *maListeSousTypes4;
    NSMutableArray *maListeSousTypes5;
}

@property NSString *selectedType;
@property NSString *selectedArray;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelType;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelSousType;
```

And this is my code for ViewController.m:

```
@synthesize selectedType;
@synthesize selectedArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    selectedType=[[NSString alloc]init];
    selectedArray=[[NSString alloc]init];

    maListeTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [maListeTypes addObject:@"Type 1"];
    [maListeTypes addObject:@"Type 2"];

    maListeSousTypes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"Sous-type 1"];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"Sous-type 2"];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"Sous-type 3"];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"Sous-type 4"];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"Sous-type 5"];

    maListeSousTypes2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"22222"];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"22222"];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"22222"];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"22222"];
    [maListeSousTypes addObject:@"22222"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Méthode pour déterminer le nombre de colonnes dans chaque picker view
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}

//Méthode pour déterminer le nombre de rangées dans chaque picker view
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(component==0){
        return [maListeTypes count];
    }
    else if(component==1){
        if([selectedType isEqualToString:@"Type 1"]){
            return [maListeSousTypes count];
        }
        else if([selectedType isEqualToString:@"Type 2"]){
            return [maListeSousTypes2 count];
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

//Méthode pour indiquer quoi afficher comme choix dans chaque picker view
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(component==0){
        return [maListeTypes objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else{
        if([selectedType isEqualToString:@"Type 1"]){
            return [maListeSousTypes objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else{
            return [maListeSousTypes2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }
    }
}

//Méthode pour indiquer quelle action va se produire lorsqu'on clique sur un des choix des picker views
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if(component==0){
        selectedType=[maListeTypes objectAtIndex:row];
        [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
        _labelType.text=[maListeTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    }
    else if(component==1){
        _labelSousType.text=[maListeSousTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    }
}
```

When my first component selection is the first choice "Type 1", in my second component I see data from NSMutableArray "maListeSousTypes" and "maListeSousTypes2" one after another like here:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o7Uu.png)

When "Type 2" is selected from the first component, my second component is empty.

Comment: You never add anything to `maListeSousTypes2`. You've copy and pasted wrong I suspect. `[maListeSousTypes addObject:@"22222"];` is just adding to `maListeSousTypes` which you have already added a bunch to `NSString`s to previously.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was missing and was not looking at the right part of my code. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be simpler than what you're doing. Let me show you how I did it in a quick example:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *leftComponentItems; // Items from this array will populate the left component
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rightComponentItemsA; // Items from this array will populate the right component, when the 1st row of the left component is selected
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rightComponentItemsB; // Items from this array will populate the right component, when the 2nd row of the left component is selected

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger selectedLeftRow; // This keeps track of the selected row on the left component (you could take that from the datasource as well)

@end
```

and then in your implementation:

```
@implementation ViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.selectedLeftRow = 0;

    self.leftComponentItems = @[@"first", @"second"];

    self.rightComponentItemsA = @[@"A1", @"A2", @"A3", @"A4", @"A5"];
    self.rightComponentItemsB = @[@"B1", @"B2", @"B3", @"B4", @"B5", @"B6", @"B7"];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2; // We have left & right components, this will always be "2"
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0) {
        return self.leftComponentItems.count;
    }

    if (component == 1) {
        if (self.selectedLeftRow == 0) {
            return self.rightComponentItemsA.count;
        } else {
            return self.rightComponentItemsB.count;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (component == 0) {
        return self.leftComponentItems[row];
    }

    if (component == 1) {
        if (self.selectedLeftRow == 0) {
            return self.rightComponentItemsA[row];
        } else {
            return self.rightComponentItemsB[row];
        }
    }

    return @"default";

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0) {
        self.selectedLeftRow = row; // We keep track of the selected row
        [pickerView reloadComponent:1]; // When we select a row in the left component, update the data on the right component
    }
}

@end
```

Feel free to ask if you don't understand something.

Comment: This is too complicated for a beginner like me unfortunately. I meant to do something simple like the code I have but I feel like there is something missing that I just cannot see.

I just need to know why my second component does not have any data and adapt the code as close to what mine looks like, regardless of the memory this app takes or the more professional way to do it as it is for a beginner's purpose.

Comment: I think that my code is similar to yours. Since your question is not very clear, I thought it would be easier to demonstrate a working example. Study the code and ask if you don't understand something.